# How to select randomly change XLS workbook filename using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

A program create and open XLS workbook with random filename ending. E.g : Jobs, Jobs(0-500), Jobs(0-599). This workbook was not yet saved. Saving the workbook was not required.

```
Windows("Jobs(0-178)").Activate
```

this VBA only work if the filename is same.

I wanted to create Excel Macro to copy the data from Job(0-500) to my workbook.

Can someone help?

Thanks.

Update :

Currently, my VBA only can read the wordbook name if the filename is specific, which is "Jobs in Lab". If the output filename changed, E.G : "Jobs in Lab(0-123), the macro could not read it.

Below is my current VBA,

```
Sub StartMacro()
Windows("Jobs in Lab").Activate
Range("A1:P500").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Jobs in Lab - Macro.xlsm").Activate  
End Sub
```

I've tried using

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook

    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like "Jobs in Lab*" Then
            wb.Activate
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next wb
End Sub
```

But, this VBA only work if i save the workbook first.

Comment: you need to be MUCH clearer what it is you are asking. Please try to tell us what you want to achieve, what results you are getting, and why they are the wrong results?
Also, one line of code isn't sufficient for us to provide useful, meaningful assistance, please post the entire procedure, or code block.

Comment: Thanks @Philip Added more info.

Answer (score 0):

you could try opening the FileDialog to allow the user to select the workbook, open it, and use the filename in your code

something like

```
function GetFilePath() as string

    Set myFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    With myFile
        .Title = "Choose File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then
            GetFilePath
            Exit Sub
        End If
        GetFilePath= .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

End function
```

and in your code you would use:

```
dim sFilename as string
sFileName=GetFilePath

if sFileName<>"" then
    workbooks(sFileName).open
    ' copy the data
end if
```

you could also use:

```
sfilename = Application.GetOpenFilename
```

HTH
Philip